# At what point do releases become supported on AskUbuntu?

Tags: discussion

Is there a policy regarding at what point a future release becomes supported?  In a couple of questions today (the comments) it has been suggested that support might be at the official release point, or at the final beta release.

[About wifi driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964647/about-wifi-driver?noredirect=1#comment1543598_964647)

and

[How to get vanilla gnome in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-to-get-vanilla-gnome-in-ubuntu-17-10/964599?noredirect=1#comment1543537_964599)

In the first question, I think that the sequence of events that would be required to assist the OP would be the same regardless of the version of Ubuntu being used.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. A release gets on-topic as soon it is released ;-)